# ggplot2 continuous bar plot with multiple factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, continuous

I'm going to use the diamond data set that comes standard with the ggplot2 package to illustrate what I'm looking for.

I want to build a graph that is like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

However, instead of having a count, I would like to return the mean of a continuous variable. I'd like to return cut and color and get the mean carat. If I put in this code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, fill=cut)) + geom_bar(position="dodge")
```

My output is a count of the number of carats vs the cut.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a new data frame with `mean(carat)` grouped by `cut` and `color` and then plot:

```
library(plyr)
data <- ddply(diamonds, .(cut, color), summarise, mean_carat = mean(carat))
ggplot(data, aes(color, mean_carat,fill=cut))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge")
```

[image]

If you want faster solutions you can use either `dplyr` or `data.table`

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- group_by(diamonds, cut, color)%.%summarise(mean_carat=mean(carat))
```

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.table(diamonds)[,list(mean_carat=mean(carat)), by=c('cut', 'color')]
```

The code for the plot is the same for both.

Comment: Awesome! I have coded the rest of my documents using data.table, so I was wondering whether there was a data.table solution to this as well. I'm also using sets of extremely large amounts of data, so the speed bonus is noticed.

Comment: Yes you can do it both with `dplyr` and `data.table` and they are faster then `plyr` I will post the solutions!

Comment: I love you so much I could kiss you. In an hour, you've solved my problems that I've slaved over for the last week and 3 different packages!